# Training neural network on skewed dataset: output always 1

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, python, backpropagation

I'm learning neural networks, and wrote a network from scratch using numpy and pandas. I'm training it using stochastic gradient descent to predict house prices. The dataset is right-skewed, I mean-normalized variables other than the target, the predictor variables are of types binary and numerical. The activation function is sigmoid.

The problem I'm facing is that the output on test data is around 1 for all observations, the actual price has to be the order of 100k.
I tried normalizing the target, price, in training set, then the output on test data was close to zero for all inputs.

This is how I initialized the weights and biases(sizes is a list containing number of neurons in each layer)

```
self.biases = [np.random.normal(0.0,b**-.5,(b,1)) for b in self.sizes[1:]]
self.weights = [np.random.normal(0.0,y**.5,(x,y)) for x,y in zip(self.sizes[1:],self.sizes[:-1])]
```

What should I do in order to get reasonable outputs.

[image: Histogram of selling price of houses]

Comment: Do you mean your network, when fitted on test data give you a regression of 1 in most cases for house prices? (I want this be true, as a buyer) How did you train the model? How could your training produce such rubbish model?

Comment: When fitted on the test data, did you also normalize the predictors?

Comment: @StudentT Yes, I did normalize the predictors for test data also

Comment: Did you look at the training error? Surely, if the target variables in the training sales are proper housing price, you can't possibly have good RMSE.

Comment: Furthermore, did you have enough training data? Your histogram plot doesn't show the scaling for your y-axis. Maybe you never converged?

Comment: @StudentT Yes, the RMSE is really high, for training data, and it decreases really slowly. I was also afraid that I wasn't running it enough to converge, so I even tried 5000 epochs, but still nothing close to a reasonable value.

Comment: That means, your model never converged. How many samples you have? How many layers in your network? What's the architecture for your network?

Comment: There are 1500 samples in the training set. The input layer has 200 neurons, hidden layer 100, and output is just one neuron.

Comment: 100 hidden layers for 1500 samples? Are you sure? Please double-check.

Comment: @StudentT Sorry, I meant 100 neurons in the hidden layer. There is only one hidden layer

Comment: This might be a ridiculous comment, but did you accidentally put your output into a sigmoid function?

Comment: @transmetro I was thinking the same thing. Please check OP. Are you sure you weren't doing logistic regression?

Comment: @transmetro You're right, I passed the output also to sigmoid. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well I'm glad it all worked out in the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sigmoid function, pictured below, squeezes all input to fit between $0$ and $1$, as you probably know. Even a super-bad fit should probably produce some outputs above $1$ which made me suspect that you had passed your final prediction to a sigmoid function by mistake. The sigmoid function is only appreciably different from $0$ or $1$ maybe in the range $x \in [-5, 5]$.

[image]